# 8 bit-increment register with load and clear

Tags: load, register

I am quite new to design circuits topic and i have one question regarding to my assignment question.

I've a simple assignment to create circuit below :

[image: Question]

I've worked on logisim to create this circuit with logism's counter such as like this :

[image: 8-bit-incrementer]

And this is working as requested... The main question is that, what if i  try to make this counter via my implementation using flip-flops, how may i put clear,load,increment inputs to circuit and how should be design ?

I am just trying to learn design things better and any help would be appreciated for me.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to learn this is to inspect something that already does the job:

See the schematic for [this counter](http://www.ti.com/product/SN74LV163A/description) (in the datasheet).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is **[here](http://cache.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT161_CNV.pdf?pspll=1http://cache.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT161_CNV.pdf?pspll=1)** and, excerpted from the data sheet for your immediate perusal, we have:

[image]